# Erlang web frameworks survey

Tags: web-framework, erlang

(Inspired by similar question on Haskel)

There are several web frameworks for Erlang like Nitrogen, Chicago Boss, and Zotonic, and  a few more.

In what aspects do they differ from each other? For example:

1. features (e.g. server only, or also client scripting, easy support for different kinds of database)
2. maturity (e.g. stability, documentation quality)
3. scalability (e.g. performance, handy abstraction)

main targets

Also, what are examples of real-world sites / web apps using these frameworks?

EDIT: Starting a bounty in hopes that it will get some conversation going

Comment: RELATED QUESTION: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025234/websites-web-applications-using-erlang (re: "examples of real-world sites")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the Chicago Boss Wiki provides a good comparison of Erlang Web-Frameworks regarding Features, Technologies, Databases, Templates etc.

Check this --> https://github.com/evanmiller/ChicagoBoss/wiki/Comparison-of-Erlang-Web-Frameworks

Comment: I've seen that, also looking for feedback on how enjoyable they are to use etc.

Comment: I just can say something about Zotonic, with which a friend of mine works and he`s is pleased with that.

Answer (score 4):

I built MaxClass.com - a new social network on top of Zotonic and am so pleased with the speed and flexibility of the platform that I started developing other high performance applications based on Zotonic.
Besides obvious things (radical scalability, benefits of Erlang etc) Zotonic has built in support for templating (Django) and a great backend that has the look and feel of a WordPress but is all super fast and easily extendable. for real life sites and systems this is really important for the less technical people in a project.

Comment: Can't understand why you were downvoted?!

Answer (score 3):

I have been learning about Erlang frameworks recently, but I haven't tested many. The one I liked best was [Erlang Web](http://www.erlang-web.org/). It has an active development community and it isn't as tightly connected to the web server as the frameworks that uses mochiweb are. I like to use a stand alone web server like e.g. [Yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org/). The new [erlang.org website](http://www.erlang.org/) is using Erlang Web.

Frameworks like Chicago Boss, BeepBeep and Zotonic doesn't have support for the Yaws web server, but Mochiweb. Mochiweb is more of a web server library than a stand alone web server, this make me turn away from them. Erlyweb seem to be a good framework available for Yaws web server, but it isn't developed anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The comparison of Erlang web frameworks has been moved to Github:

https://github.com/evanmiller/ChicagoBoss/wiki/Comparison-of-Erlang-Web-Frameworks